# Dropdown pushes screen focus down using UIKit

Tags: javascript, css, getuikit

I'm using [UIKit](http://getuikit.com/) to make a dropdown. The dropdown hovers over the content, which is wanted behaviour for me. When the button is so close to the bottom of the screen that it won't have enough space to show the dropdown itself totally, it pushes the screen focus down. I'm not quite sure what's causing this, the dropdown itself gets `display:block;` when the button is clicked, but it needs that to be visible.

Is there some way to open the dropdown, but without the screen jumping to the bottom? (So people can see they're missing content and their reaction should be to scroll down a bit?)

I made a Codepen to show what's happening. http://codepen.io/InstaK/pen/GWYwdM

Comment: Beginner here trying to understand the issue. Are you saying that when the dropdown is clicked, it always shows options downwards and not a default auto behavior as show option top/bottom depending on the content and available screen?

Comment: Well, the default auto behaviour is the dropdown even coming out of your browser... If you add a lot of options here and make your window smaller you will see the dropdown comes out of it 
( https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select ). I would like to achieve that behaviour, but unfortunately because I don't use a select tag I'm afraid I'll never be able to let another html element come out of the browser. Also, I can change the options-showing direction with UIKit by adding the value {preventflip: true} to my html-element. If you remove that, the options show upwards.

Comment: I apologize but I am still not able to understand the issue. Hope someone else could help you with it.

Comment: I understand it's something difficult to understand... If you go to my codepen and make sure my button is really close to the bottom of the screen (for example like this: https://puu.sh/v29c7/67fe3ae3d3.png) and then you would click the button, you would see that the screen jumps downwards to show the content of the dropdown. I want my screen to stay at the very same position just as before the click.

Comment: NOW I understand! Well I've never used UIkit before so I cannot say much....But this could be a browser issue as I do not face the same on firefox. I see the behavior you mentioned on chrome. Let me see if I could find a solution for the same.

Comment: Aha, you're right... It does not happen on firefox... Still don't have a clue about what's triggering this though.

Comment: Well I tried alot of searching and all however wasn't able to get the reason behind. But I guess upgrading to the newer version would help you out?

Also you loaded the scripts in the wrong sequence.

Comment: The newer version of what? UIKit or Chrome? Also, I put the script on purpose at the end, I want the content to load sooner than my scripts.

Comment: newer version of UIKit. It has different syntax for dropdowns.
Also you are loading 2 jquery versions. And what i meant by wrong sequence was that you are supposed to load the jquery script BEFORE the UIkit script.

Comment: Ah fair enough, I thought the jquery loader from codepen wasn't working, that's why I added the script because UIKit kept saying it didn't find jQuery... Stupid of me.